# Android WallpaperManager scales Bitmap too small

Tags: android, bitmap, scale, center, wallpaper

the WallpaperManager scales the wallpaper too small on some devices. I used the following code.

```
    Bitmap srcBitmap = .....
    WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager
                .getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    int height = wm.getDesiredMinimumHeight();
    int width = wm.getDesiredMinimumWidth();
    wm.setBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(srcBitmap, width , height , true);
```

On the galaxy note with android 4.0.4 the wallpaper fills the full screen. But on galaxy s2 with 2.3 the wallpaper fills only a small rectangle in the center of the screen.

greetings,

mp5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem was that `wm.getDesiredMinimumHeight();` and `wm.getDesiredMinimumWidth();` return -1 on some devices. So `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(srcBitmap, width , height , true);` failed and the original size of `srcBitmap` was used.

Answer (score 0):

well this will fits the screen with your bitmap width and height

```
    WallpaperManager wallmanage = (WallpaperManager) getSystemService(WALLPAPER_SERVICE);
wallmanager.setBitmap(bitmap);
wallmanager.suggestDesiredDimensions(w, h);

where w = bitmap.getWidth();  
and   h = bitmap.getHeight();
```